# GitHub Pages showing Empty Page for React App

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, web-deployment, github-pages

I have hosted a simple static react app on github pages, Made all changes in package.json

But first the link was showing 404, I searched on the internet and tried adding a ? at the end of the link which resulted in the link showing a blank page.

Its showing a blank page now! I have tried all the solutions such as;
i. switching master and gh-pages branches
ii. adding ? at the end of the link
iii. changing "private" : true, in package.json to false
iv. adding /index.html at the end of the link
v. adding new commits and redeploying the app

These solutions didn't work, any help would be appreciated!!

link: https://iqramalik21.github.io/monsters-rolodex/
git repo: https://github.com/iqramalik21/monsters-rolodex

Comment: Can you post your git repo

Comment: I have added the link as well as the git repo

Answer (score 0):

Couple of steps you need to follow exactly:

1. Create a new Repo and Enter username.github.io as the repository name. Replace username with your GitHub username. For example, if your username is octocat, the repository name should be octocat.github.io.
2. In your project(the one with your codebase) terminal run `npm run build` this will create a build folder in your project directory.
3. Push only the contents of the build folder onto the new repo you created with username.github.io name.

That's it you will start to see on your GitHub page!!

> Note: Your page is hosted on the root route.